# Sort Items by list element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have i txt file that i need to sort the info in by a certain element.
this would be the original file

```
Wheaton,Will,7
Parker,Peter,9
Apple,Adam,1
Jones,Mike,10
Potter,Harry,7
```

it the file to be sorted by the third element so that the file will read

```
Apple,Adam,1
Wheaton,Will,7
Potter,Harry,7
Parker,Peter,9
Jones,Mike,10
```

I have tried using

```
allItems = []
for i in info:
    data = i.rstrip('\n').split(',')
    allItems.append(data)

allItems.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
```

but it didnt work. how can i organize by list element. Also will python automatically alphabetize the lines or will I have to do it sepatately

Comment: *but neither one works*. **How** did it not work? What was the output you got instead?

Comment: Have you tried `key=itemgetter(2)` instead of that lambda?

* `from operator import itemgetter`

Comment: Your first attempt (at least as posted) switches from `data` to `lists` as the thing to sort.

Comment: nothing changed my file was the same

Comment: @MartijnPieters I needed the information in the third element regardless of that element being a number or a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings, so `'1'` < `'10'` < `'7'` < `'9'`. Convert them to int.

```
with open('info.txt', 'r') as f:
      data = [line.split(',') for line in f]
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[2])))
```

Comment: I need it sorted in the file not printed

Comment: I think you may have to read the data, sort it and then write back.@derpyherp

Comment: how would I sort it, the same way I tried before? And how would I write it back afterwards

Comment: The sort method I have given in my answer. Basically you should add a `int()` so you can sort by the number correctly. As for writing back, `with open(file, 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(data))`@derpyherp

Comment: Yeah. And `data` should be the data you post in your question, and `file` is a filename you want to write the output to.@derpyherp

Comment: You should use `'\n'.join` to first make the list to be a string.@derpyherp

Comment: error sequence item 0 expected str sequence, list found @zhangyangyu

Comment: I have told you in the above comment. You should first use `'\n'.join` to make the list a string. `f.write('\n'.join(sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))))`@derpyherp

Comment: `with open('info.txt', 'r') as f:`
      `data = [line.split(',') for line in f]`
`with open(file, 'w') as f:`
      `f.write('\n'.join(sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))))`
this is my code but i still got the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33784/discussion-between-derpyherp-and-zhangyangyu)